# Create a list of dictionaries in a dictionary from csv in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
Name;Category;Address
McFood;Fast Food;Street 1
BurgerEmperor;Fast Food;Way 1
BlueFrenchHorn;French;Street 12
PetesPizza;Italian;whatever
SubZero;Fast Food;Highway 6
```

and I want to make a dictionary with the category as keys and a list of dictionaries with the remaining data as values. So it shall look like this:

```
{'Fast Food' : [{'Name': 'McFood', 'Address': 'Street 1'}, 
                {'Name': 'BurgerEmperor', 'Address': 'Way 1'}],
                ...],
 'French' : [{'Name': 'BlueFrenchHorn', 'Address': 'Street12'}],
...}
```

(indentation here for better readability).

I tried it like the following snippet but I do not get anywhere from there:

```
import csv
mydict={}

with open ('food.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        #sniff to find the format
        fileDialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        #read the CSV file into a dictionary
        dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect=fileDialect)
        for row in dictReader:
            mycategory= row["Category"]
            del row("Category")
            mydict[mycategory]=row
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)  # <---

with open ('food.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    fileDialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect=fileDialect)
    for row in dictReader:
        mycategory= row.pop("Category")
        mydict[mycategory].append(row)  # Will put a list for not-existing key

mydict = dict(mydict)  # Convert back to a normal dictionary (optional)
```