# DictReader for Excel-Files

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I have a file that I currently save to csv but it's originally an Excel-file (Excel 2010).

Its content is of this sort:

```
Name;Category;Address
McFood;Fast Food;Street 1
BurgerEmperor;Fast Food;Way 1
BlueFrenchHorn;French;Street 12
PetesPizza;Italian;whatever
SubZero;Fast Food;Highway 6
```

I save it as csv to being able to parse it. At the moment I use DictReader ([here is the code and a corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891451/create-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-dictionary-from-csv-in-python))

Is there something like the DictReader available for an Excel-module like xlrd?
How would I have to change my code?

Comment: May be worth checking out this: https://gist.github.com/639082/26a146bcd801969318f5eacf82170de898d52260

Comment: That worked. Great little script! Thanks. If you posted this as an answer, I could vote it as the accepted answer :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted this as an answer to potentially help those looking for a similar solution. There is a gist on github (not mine) that contains a potential solution. Might need a few tweaks to apply to your particular situation: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mdellavo/639082)

For those who do not wish to click, here is the code:

```
try:
    import xlrd
    import mmap

    def XLSDictReader(f, sheet_index=0):
        data    = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        book    = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
        sheet   = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)

        def item(i, j):
            return (sheet.cell_value(0,j), sheet.cell_value(i,j))

        return ( dict(item(i,j) for j in range(sheet.ncols)) \
                     for i in range(1, sheet.nrows) )

except ImportError:
    XLSDictReader = None
```

Comment: Thanks. In the gist you can find an improved version as well. The only tweak it needs is to re-add the import of mmap.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [gist for an openpyxl implementation](https://gist.github.com/dnk8n/925db332579a539f9dea37301906fd45)

Here it is, repeated for convenience:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Iterator, List, Optional, Union

from openpyxl import load_workbook


def xlsx_dictreader(
    filename: Union[str, Path],
    sheet_index: int = 0,
    header_row_index: int = 1,
    data_start_row_index: int = 2,
    data_only: bool = True,
    post_process_funcs: Optional[List[Callable[[Any], Any]]] = None,
    null_vals: List[Union[None, str]] = [None, "None"],
) -> Iterator[Dict[str, Any]]:
    book = load_workbook(filename, data_only=data_only)
    sheet = book.worksheets[sheet_index]
    header = [
        c
        for c in (cell.value for cell in sheet[header_row_index])
        if c not in null_vals
    ]
    if not post_process_funcs:
        post_process_funcs = [lambda x: x] * len(header)
    else:
        if len(post_process_funcs) != len(header):
            raise Exception(
                "post-processing functions do not line up with headers"
            )
    for row_idx in range(data_start_row_index, sheet.max_row + 1):
        candidate = {}
        for col_idx in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
            if col_idx <= len(header):
                candidate[header[col_idx - 1]] = post_process_funcs[
                    col_idx - 1
                ](sheet.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx).value)
        if not all(value in null_vals for value in candidate.values()):
            yield candidate
```

There is more detail avalable in the gist comments

Comment: It is basically the same as the original answer, except I some increased customizability. Some of it might only be useful to me, but even if so, the defaults give you what you need .

Comment: I am interested to learn myself, so please comment here and/or on the gist if you have advice.