# Convert csv- or Excel-file (xlsx) to kml with custom markers

Tags: python, excel, csv, kml, google-earth

I want to convert a csv- or Excel(2010)-file to kml to being able to show it on google earth.
The file holds addresses that are not geocoded.
It holds a field with a url for a custom marker.
And it holds a field with some info that I want to show in a info window.

The file looks like this:

```
Name;Category;Address; Icon; Info
McFood;Fast Food;Street 1, zip, town, country; url-to-icon; Info
BurgerEmperor;Fast Food;Way 1, zip, town, country; url-to-icon; Info
BlueFrenchHorn;French;Street 12, zip, town, country; url-to-icon; Info
PetesPizza;Italian;whatever, zip, town, country; url-to-icon; Info
SubZero;Fast Food;Highway 6, zip, town, country; url-to-icon; Info
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this - it would be great if you explained why.
The intention of the question - and the given answer was to show a solution to a problem that I had that might be of use for someone in the whole internetz.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the community I want to share my solution to this problem.
It may be a little rough around the edges, but it works. I wrote two scripts (one for csv-input and one for xlsx-input that only differ slightly).

**CSV-to-KML:**

```
import csv
import simplekml
import geocoder
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)

# the part of reading the file to a dictionary is taken from
# http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/python-read-csv-file-list-dictionary.html
# and modified to have a list of dictionaries - solution from
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891451/create-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-dictionary-from-csv-in-python/

with open ('food.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    #sniff to find the format
    fileDialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    #read the CSV file into a dictionary
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect=fileDialect)
    for row in dictReader:
        mycategory = row.pop("category")
        mydict[mycategory].append(row)  # Will put a list for not-existing key

mydict = dict(mydict) # Convert back to a normal dictionary (optional)

# Use SimpleKml to write kml-file
# category from csv-file used as folder
# Custom Markers taken from url in csv-file

kml =simplekml.Kml()
for ctgy in mydict:
    fol=kml.newfolder(name=ctgy)
    for entry in mydict[ctgy]:
        # geocode addresses
        g = geocoder.google(entry["Address"])
        pnt=fol.newpoint(name=entry["Name"], coords=[(g.lng,g.lat)], description=entry["Info"])
        if entry["Icon"] != "":
            pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href=entry["Icon"]
kml.save("food.kml")
```

**XLSX-to-KML:**

It differs only slightly - to being able to use a DictReader with an excel-file I use xlsdictreader.py from the answer to this question:
[DictReader for Excel-Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894917/dictreader-for-excel-files)

The differences are:

```
# import csv
from xlsdictreader import XLSDictReader
```

and in file handling:

```
with open ('food.xlsx', 'r') as excelfile:
    dictReader = XLSDictReader(excelfile)
```

**Please comment**

Feel free to use the scripts.
And please comment on how to improve it as I am relatively new to python.